# Is there a way that I can make chrome extension that reloads the page if chrome says that "The site cannot be reached"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that reloads the page if the site cannot be reached. I know the site reload command, but I am not able to figure out the code for it. Can you please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred) API in the background script.

background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(info => {
  if (!info.frameId && info.error === 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED') {
    chrome.tabs.reload(info.tabId);
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked for me with just a minor change-

Comment: `info.error === 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'`

Comment: Although, it works perfectly fine but I do get an error - `Unchecked runtime.lastError: No tab with id: 27.
`

Comment: Sounds like the tab was closed. You can hide the error: chrome.tabs.reload(info.tabId, () => chrome.runtime.lastError)

Comment: Would you know how to resolve a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error?

Comment: I guess you'd have to change/update your system DNS config. This can only be done by running an external utility that you can register and launch via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: is there a way that I can show a page(html maybe) other than the error page while the site reloads?

Comment: chrome.tabs.update(info.tab.id, {url: '.....'}, () => !chrome.runtime.lastError && chrome.tabs.update(info.tab.id, {url: info.url}, () => chrome.runtime.lastError)) where .... can be a `data:` URI for your html or a path to html file in your extension.

Comment: tab.id or tabId?

Comment: Ah, `info.tabId`

Comment: also where should I put this line in the code(coz I am not getting what I want)?...and if I have a html file index.html in the same folder, should the code be '{url:'data:index.html'}'

Comment: Looks like I've answered 5 questions already here so let's stop.

Comment: [background script](https://web.archive.org/web/20231031113105/https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages) link is 404 now and the Manifest V3 version is https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/service-workers

Comment: There are millions of such links broken in the new documentation site, so it might make more sense for them to restore support for the old links. I've reported it [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/gR-l6EkUc50).